# Expected variance and kurtosis from PMF in which possible discrete values are drawn randomly in advance

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a generative process that produces data samples as follows:

- a) There is a predetermined amount $m$ of “slots” with associated probabilities that sum to 1. These are given and not random.
- b) A sample of numbers is drawn uniformly at random $\sim \mathrm{Unif}(0, 1)$ for each of the slots in step `a)`.
- c) An undefined amount of numbers is drawn from a discrete probability mass function that samples from the numbers that were determined in `b)` with associated probabilities given in step `a)`.

If I am given the coefficients from step `a)`, then start constructing different samples by following `b)` and `c)`, and take the variance and kurtosis of those samples, how can the **expected** variance and kurtosis be expressed in terms of the coefficients given in a) ?

(Expected variance and kurtosis from a resulting sample drawn in step `c)`, given that step `b)` must also be repeated)

Variance is given by $\mathrm{Var}[x] = E[x^2] – E^2[x]$, while kurtosis is given by
 $$\kappa(x) = E\left[ \Bigl(\frac{x - \bar{x}}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}[x]}} \Bigr)^4 \right]~,$$ 
or alternatively $\mathrm{Var}[z^2]+1$ (where $z$ is the standardized value of $x$ obtained by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation: $Z = \dfrac{x - \bar{x}}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}[x]}}$, and $\bar{x}$ denotes the mean).

The problem would be very easy without step `b)` , that is, $V(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} p_i m_i^2 - \left( \sum_{i=1}^{m} p_i m_i \right)^2$, but I'm wondering how could it be solved like this.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll answer myself after playing around with software for symbolic maths.

For kurtosis: there doesn’t seem to be a way to express it in a simple manner in terms of the initial coefficients.

For variance, assuming $m$ slots, it can be obtained recursively assuming the variance is already calculated with one slot left out
$$
E[\text{Var}_m(x)] = E[\text{Var}_{m-1}(x)] - \sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\frac{p_i p_m}{2} - \frac{p_m^2}{3}  + \frac{p_m}{3}
$$

With
$$
E[\text{Var}_2(x)] = - \frac{p_1^2}{3} - \frac{p_1 p_2}{2} + \frac{p_1}{3} - \frac{p_2^2}{3} + \frac{p_2}{3}
$$

Sample python code:

```
def Evar(p):
    ### p is a numpy array
    n = p.shape[0]
    r = -p[0]**2/3 - p[0]*p[1]/2 + p[0]/3 - p[1]**2/3 + p[1]/3
    for i in range(2, n):
        for j in range(i):
            r -= p[j] * p[i] / 2
        r += p[i] / 3 - p[i]**2 / 3
    return r
```